# Restricting HTTP traffic from within a docker container

Tags: docker, iptables

I need to make sure that only HTTPS traffic comes out of a docker container.

What is the best way to restrict HTTP (or any other port) coming out of a container?

The container itself does not listen on any port. A tool inside the container makes HTTP/HTTPS requests to pull a license. I need to make sure it can only do HTTPS requests.

Is it best to block the traffic on the docker host side?

Like this:

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i ext_if -p tcp --dport http -j REJECT
```

I don't want to mess up all the tables that Docker creates upon initialisation.

Comment: comunication rules are supposed to be controlled from the host take a look https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/container-communication/#communicating-to-the-outside-world

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to restrict traffic on a specific container (not on host level, not for all containers), you have to add a firewall rule in the container. Here is an example:

Run the container with the [NET_ADMIN capability](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities)

```
docker run --rm -it --cap-add=NET_ADMIN  debian
```

Install iptables and curl

```
apt update && apt install iptables curl
```

Add a firewall rule

```
ptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
```

Then test the rule with:

```
curl http://www.google.com
curl https://www.google.com
```

Comment: Yes, just one specific container. Did not know about the net_admin cap. Cheers for that. I was wondering why iptables does not work inside the container... Will try the solution shortly